# How can I make the legend numbers and text in bold?

Tags: r, lattice

I am plotting 2 rasters using this:

```
spplot(r, colorkey = list(space = "bottom", height = 1)) + 
  spplot(merged, cex=0.5, col.regions="green") 
grid.text('Test', y=unit(0.025, "npc"), 
          rot=360, x=unit(0.5, "npc"))
```

How can I make the following things in **bold** and/or increase the size - a) Tick Numbers b) Legend Title

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unsure about this answer. But, would setting the gp argument work in this case?

```
grid.text('Test', y=unit(0.025, "npc"), 
          rot=360, x=unit(0.5, "npc"),
          gp=gpar(fontsize = 20, fontface="bold"))
```

Answer (score 3):

For the tick numbers, try adding `font = 2`?

```
colorkey = list(space = "bottom", height = 1, labels = list(font = 2))
```

Damiano Fantini's solution works for me for the legend title.